# How to configure unmanaged resource directory in sbt-jacoco 3.0.2?

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage, jacoco

**Current behaviour**

I was using the old version of jacoco over this configuration:

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.6")
```

**build.sbt**

```
...

jacoco.settings

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test += baseDirectory.value / "test/resources"
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "devops/cookbooks/thex_data_server/files/default/evolutions/default"

...
```

**Expected Behaviour**

Now I'm migrating to use the jacoco over this configuration:

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-jacoco" % "3.0.2")
```

**build.sbt**

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test += baseDirectory.value / "test/resources"
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "devops/cookbooks/thex_data_server/files/default/evolutions/default"
```

**Environment**

```
SBT version: 0.13.5
Plugin version: 3.0.2
Scala version(s): 2.11.7
Java version: 1.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by following this example: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jacoco/tree/master/src/sbt-test/sbt-jacoco/unmanaged-resources

If anyone has any questions, please let me know.